# Description of the stress in an elastic ring

Tags: elasticity

How can one describe in terms of elasticity the stress necessary to stretch an elastic ring of Young Modulus $E$ and rest radius $R_0$, and width $d$ ?

My guess is that in the linear regime, the force can be written :

$F=k(R-R_0)$

with :

$k=E\frac{4\pi R_0^2}{d}$ for an elastic sphere, and $k=E\frac{2\pi R d_1}{d_2}$ for a ring where $d_1$ is the width perpendicular to the radius and $d_2$ the width in the radial direction.

Hence the stress writes respectively : $\sigma=E(R-R_0)/d$ and $\sigma=E(R-R_0)/d_2$
[image]
is it ok ?

Comment: A diagram would be helpful. As the question stands, it's unclear where the force is applied, where the stretching occurs, and what orientation is being assumed when discussing the stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hoop strain is $$\epsilon_{\theta}=\frac{(2\pi R)-(2\pi R_0)}{2\pi R_0}=\frac{(R-R_0)}{R_0}$$Hence, the hoop stress is $$\sigma_{\theta}=E\frac{(R-R_0)}{R_0}$$If F represents the radial force *per unit length* applied to the ring (directed radially), then $$F(2R_0)=2\sigma_{\theta}d_1d_2=2E\frac{(R-R_0)}{R_0}d_1d_2$$or$$F=E\frac{(R-R_0)}{R_0^2}d_1d_2$$